# Custom classes & casting inside conditional statements in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting

I ran into this issue twice now, and am curious to know if there is a correct way of getting the following example to work. I know there are other ways /workarounds for doing the same thing but I am wondering why the compiler doesn't recognise my casting and if I am missing something obvious here.

Suppose I have two table views with different style header views that I need to provide. `SectionHeaderViewA` is a UIView subclass with a custom property `textLabelA`, `SectionHeaderViewB` is also a UIView subclass with a custom property `textLabelB`.

In the method:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id headerView;
    if (tableView.tag == TAG_A)
    {
        headerView = (SectionHeaderViewA*)[[SectionHeaderViewA alloc] init];
        headerView.textLabelA = ... // I am unable to access the custom property here even after casting (SectionHeaderViewA*) above.
    } else if (tableView.tag == TAG_B) {
        headerView = (SectionHeaderViewB*)[[SectionHeaderViewB alloc] init];
        headerView.textLabelB = ... // Same as above, even after casting the custom property is not recognised
    }
    return headerView;
}
```

Even after casting (SectionHeaderViewA*) and (SectionHeaderViewB*) to my headerView ivar, I am still unable to access their respective custom properties. It's like the compiler is still seeing `headerView` as an unknown / id type but why?

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: Have you imported both headers ?

Comment: Rog, does the debugger recognize the specific types of the table view when you check the type of the parameter "tableView"?

Comment: It is a bit dangerous not initialising `headerView` to `nil` as you could potentially return garbage. Also if you are not using ARC these views should be auto released.

Comment: The compiler error message is `Semantic Issue: Property 'textLabel' not found on object of type '__strong id'`

Comment: I am using ARC and because of that, headerView is automagically initialised to nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is not in the correct place. Cast headerView before sending the appropriate textLabel A or B message.

```
id headerView;
if (tableView.tag == TAG_A)  
{  
    headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewA alloc] init];
    ((SectionHeaderViewA*)headerView).textLabelA = ... // I am unable to access the custom property here even after casting (SectionHeaderViewA*) above.
} else if (tableView.tag == TAG_B) {
    headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewB alloc] init];
    ((SectionHeaderViewB*)headerView).textLabelB = ... // Same as above, even after casting the custom property is not recognized
}
return headerView;
```

Once you move the cast, you will be able to send the correct message.

Comment: My pleasure. Out of curiosity, why do you use two distinct views with different UITextLabels for your section headers?

Comment: I don't really, it was just a contrived example to get my point across. But I don't see why there couldn't have different formatting and other subviews associated with it (in my case I have 2 different header views as there are 2 different tableviews for the iPad version).

Answer (score 1):

Your cast is not doing anything as you are casting into `id`.

Whilst @sean's answer works and it does the single exit it is pretty ugly having all the curly brackets I would probably go for

```
id headerView = nil; // Initialize to nil... you may not go into either side of your if

if (TAG_A == tableView.tag) {  
    SectionHeaderViewA *sectionHeaderViewA = [[SectionHeaderViewA alloc] init];
    sectionHeaderViewA.textLabelA = ... 
    headerView = sectionHeaderViewA;
} else if (TAG_B == tableView.tag) {
    SectionHeaderViewB *sectionHeaderViewB = [[SectionHeaderViewB alloc] init];
    sectionHeaderViewB.textLabelB = ...
    headerView = sectionHeaderViewB;
}

return headerView;
```

Or another possibility (potentially over engineering the problem) is make both `sectionHeaderViewA` and `sectionHeaderViewB` conform to a protocol and then you can make it a little tidier still.

**SectionHeaderInterface.h**

```
@protocol SectionHeaderInterface <NSObject>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *textLabel;

@end
```

**SectionHeaderView(A|B).h**

```
#import "SectionHeaderInterface.h"

@interface SectionHeaderView(A|B) : UIView <SectionHeaderInterface>

// ... rest of interface

@end
```

**SectionHeaderView(A|B).m**

```
@implementation SectionHeaderView(A|B)

@synthesize textLabel = _textLabel;

// ... rest of your class

@end
```

**YourController.m**

```
id<SectionHeaderInterface> headerView = nil; // Initialize to nil... you may not go into either side of your if

if (TAG_A == tableView.tag) {  
    headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewA alloc] init];
} else if (TAG_B == tableView.tag) {
    headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewB alloc] init];
}

headerView.textLabel.text = ...

return headerView;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Paul.s, I like the idea of declaring a protocol too that both can conform to. You are right that it is over engineering for this contrived example but it could be very useful in some other cases.

Answer (score 1):

the type of headerView is "id", which means it doesn't know about your extra properties etc (the cast doesn't change the type of "headerView").

you could do something like:

```
if (tableView.tag == TAG_A)
{
    SectionHeaderViewA* headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewA alloc] init];
    headerView.textLabelA = ...
    return headerView;
} else if (tableView.tag == TAG_B) {
    SectionHeaderViewB* headerView = [[SectionHeaderViewB alloc] init];
    headerView.textLabelB = ... 
    return headerView;
}
return nil;
```

Comment: `the cast doesn't change the type of headerView`. You're right, it makes sense when I look at it that way. I'm not a big fan of the three points of return in your conditional statement so what I do is declare `headerView` outside the `if/else` and then inside the conditional do `headerView = headerViewA` or `headerView = headerViewB`, then `return headerView`.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but in the mean time, pay attention to memory leak.